# How to write a query to JSON file in C#

Tags: c#, json

I have to edit my JSON file in my C# project, but i got some problems.Moreover, i am using json.net

my JSON file deathGod.json :

```
{
  "toKillList": [
    {
      "Name": "John",
      "dieWith": "eat hot dog",
      "Date": "date",
      "State": "state"
    },
    {
      "Name": "peter",
      "dieWith": "swim",
      "Date": "date",
      "State": "state"
    }
  ]
}
```

my coding :

```
string path = @"\users\deathGod\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\killApp\killApp\deathGod.json";
string jsonData = File.ReadAllText(path);

dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonData);
JArray items = (JArray)result["toKillList"];
```

**Problem:**

i need to add a query to the JArray, then add the Jarray to JObject. However, the quotation mark and line break are kill my file.

code:

```
string element = @"{'Name':’may’,
                     ‘Path’:’driving’,
                     ‘Date’:’date’, 
                     ‘State’:’state’}";

JValue value = new JValue(element);
items .Add(value);
//JArray => JObject => json file
```

result:

```
{
  "toKillList": [
        {
          "Name": "John",
          "dieWith": "eat hot dog",
          "Date": "date",
          "State": "state"
        },
        {
          "Name": "peter",
          "dieWith": "swim",
          "Date": "date",
          "State": "state"
    },
    "{'Name':â€™mayâ€™, \r\nâ€˜Pathâ€™:â€™drivingâ€™,\r\n â€˜Dateâ€™:â€™dateâ€™,\r\n â€˜Stateâ€™:â€™stateâ€™\r\n}"
  ]
}
```

any idea?

Comment: change all `’` to `'`, also deserialize before adding to `items` or better use anonymous type

Comment: tryed not using @ but using escapes? like string element = "{ \"Name\":\"may\" ... and don't use ’ but use '

Comment: @AlekseyL. how about the"\r\n"? I want it is break the line, not "\r\n"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should build `JObject` and not `JValue`:

```
var element = JObject.FromObject(new
{
    Name = "may",
    Path = "driving",
    Date = "date",
    State = "state"
});
items.Add(element);
```

Comment: Could you answer me an extra question? How can i get an item name of a JArray? For example, how can i get "may" in items? Is `items[2]["may"]`?

Comment: I solve it, first change the JArray item to JObject in for loop, then use `obj["Name"]` to get "May"

Comment: btw, it is much more convenient to work with strongly typed objects

Comment: What do you mean about "strongly typed objects"? is class such as "person" a strongly typed object?

Comment: yes, define a class, then deserialize json to collection of this type and work with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert string into JSon firstly replace `’` with `'`. Then use the following code:

```
var element = @"{'Name':'may','Path':'driving', 'Date':'date', 'State':'state'}";

var value = (JToken)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(element);
items.Add(value);

var res = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
```

The final result is:

```
{
  "toKillList":[
     {"Name":"John","dieWith":"eat hot dog","Date":"date","State":"state"},
     {"Name":"peter","dieWith":"swim","Date":"date","State":"state"},
     {"Name":"may","Path":"driving","Date":"date","State":"state"}
  ]
}
```